# Raise docker container and set new terminal with a command inside it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to:

1. raise docker container
2. open new terminal
3. in this new terminal, move to docker container shell
4. run a command

here is my script (at this point only docker-compose up is running, then some seconds later a new terminal opens but i can not see the commands on the new console when i ran the ./script.sh

```
# Raise docker container
docker-compose up &
# open new console and keep it open
x-terminal-emulator -n -e ls &&
# enter docker container shell
docker exec -it docker-app_1 /bin/bash &&
# change dir
cd /_dev/ &
# execute command
yarn start
```

Can someone point me to the right direction please? i've no much experience creating shell scripts and there's something that i'm missing out for sure. Thanks

PD: I am running elementary OS so that is the default terminal

i think the only issue is the commands are not running in the new console and docker-compose up keeps open so they will never run in the original console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exec one command after another in docker exec, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose up &
sleep 3 &&
echo "running yarn start inside docker" &&
docker exec -it docker-app_1 /bin/bash -c "cd /_dev/; yarn start";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your should place your "change dir and execute command" to Dockerfile?

Add following line do your Dockerfile:

```
CMD cd /_dev/ && yarn start
```

CMD will execute a your script/command when container starts.

[See Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)